# Template group urls

Tags: templates, url, groups

I have a template group called 'site. These are my top level generic templates, I would like to exclude the site part of the url so,

```
http://mysite/site/aboutus
```

I would like to remove the 'site' part of the url for this group only.

Any 3rd part or core EE way to achieve this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure if you set the group to default / homepage in the cp it won't require the URL - the index page within that group will be your sites homepage.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this for all templates located within your site's *default* template group by [disabling Strict URLs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html#strict-urls). But this will only work with your default template group, no others.

Note that you should put some logic in each of these templates instructing EE to display a 404 page when accessed *with* the template group - otherwise you could run into duplicate content issues, as your content will be accessible via both `/site/about` *and* `/about`.

e.g.,

```
{if segment_1 == 'site'}{redirect="404"}{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are other reasons for putting these templates into the /site/ group I'd recommend just creating an /aboutus/ template group and putting the code into the index template.

You'd get the URLs you want without hassle/logic and just have a few more template groups in the system.